# Listing buildout configuration variables

Tags: python, buildout

I'd like to find out, exactly what variables are available when using zc.buildout.  I can always look at the source, but ideally I'd find a list somewhere, or be able to query buildout to find out what **it** thinks are the variables available at any one time.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found from the [buildout docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout#annotated-sections)  that

`bin/buildout annotate`

was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the prettiest list, but you can look at `.installed.cfg` in your buildout's directory.

For every part, it shows which options it knows about. (For some reason several parts are often shown multiple times).